# Ubuntu 18.04.01 USB won't boot live or install (Ryzen 3 2200G, GAAB350N)

Tags: 64-bit

I have seen a few posts of people successfully installing Ubuntu with the Ryzen 2200G but I can't get it to work. The farthest it has made it is a pink blurry screen.

I have tried:
1. Multiple iso's to make sure the file wasn't corrupt
2. Integrated and discrete GPUs
3. Different USB sticks
4. The USB boots fine on a different PC with a Ryzen 5 2600X and GTX 1070.

Different outcomes:
1. Pink screen
2. Black Screen
3. Scrolling text that scrolls so fast it is unreadable (With discrete GPU- GTS 250)
Any suggestions?